# Netty java getting data from ByteBuf

Tags: java, netty

How to get a byte array from `ByteBuf` efficiently in the code below? I need to get the array and then serialize it.

```
package testingNetty;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;

public class ServerHandler extends  ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
     @Override
        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
         System.out.println("Message receive");
         ByteBuf buff = (ByteBuf) msg;
             // There is I need get bytes from buff and make serialization
         byte[] bytes = BuffConvertor.GetBytes(buff);
        }

        @Override
        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) { 
            // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
            cause.printStackTrace();
            ctx.close();
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete code. Also mention the which version of netty you are using?

Comment: I use 4.0.9 version of Netty

Comment: So what's problem is? What do you mean by bytes massive in the above context?

Comment: Bytes massive means a byte[] wich contains seriziable object

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
ByteBuf buf = ...
byte[] bytes = new byte[buf.readableBytes()];
buf.readBytes(bytes);
```

If you don't want the readerIndex to change:

```
ByteBuf buf = ...
byte[] bytes = new byte[buf.readableBytes()];
int readerIndex = buf.readerIndex();
buf.getBytes(readerIndex, bytes);
```

If you want to minimize the memory copy, you can use the backing array of the `ByteBuf`, if it's available:

```
ByteBuf buf = ...
byte[] bytes;
int offset;
int length = buf.readableBytes();

if (buf.hasArray()) {
    bytes = buf.array();
    offset = buf.arrayOffset();
} else {
    bytes = new byte[length];
    buf.getBytes(buf.readerIndex(), bytes);
    offset = 0;
}
```

Please note that you can't simply use `buf.array()`, because:

- Not all `ByteBuf`s have backing array. Some are off-heap buffers (i.e. direct memory)
- Even if a `ByteBuf` has a backing array (i.e. `buf.hasArray()` returns `true`), the following isn't necessarily true because the buffer might be a slice of other buffer or a pooled buffer:

  - `buf.array()[0] == buf.getByte(0)`
  - `buf.array().length == buf.capacity()`

Comment: [@user2132106 would like to know](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28122795/2778484) if he can do `byte[] ar= buf.array()` (if I understand the post correctly).

Comment: Updated the answer for him.

Comment: @trustin what's the purpose of the `offset` here?

Comment: I tested with real data: the second way (minimize the memory copy) is wrong. Java platform: Oracle 1.8; netty version: 4.1.58.Final.

Comment: @Fireburn `offset` tells at which position in the array the first byte starts.

Comment: @trustin -- tested the second method and I occasionally got wrong byte array contents. May be need careful consideration and add some protection?

Comment: @zipper May be you are not using offset while reading data from byte array.

Comment: What happens to `bytes` in third approach if it was initialized in first block i.e. `bytes = buf.array()` and later buf was released - `buf.release()` ?

Answer (score 6):

Another option is `ByteBufUtil.getBytes(ByteBuf buf, int start, int length, boolean copy)`

See [ByteBufUtil](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBufUtil.html#getBytes-io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf-)

Comment: There is indeed an option to share the array instead of copying it (if possible)

Comment: Thanks @TuomasKiviaho . I updated my answer per your comment.