# Getting string from netty ByteBuf

Tags: java, netty, bytebuffer

How can I get the string from a netty `ByteBuf`? As of now I am able to get it character by character. Is there a way to get the string object directly?

```
// message is of type ByteBuf
for (int i = 0; i < message.capacity(); i++) {
    byte b = message.payload().getByte(i);
    System.out.print((char) b);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the provided method [ByteBuf.toString(Charset)](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#toString(java.nio.charset.Charset)) .

Answer (score 4):

use `ByteBuf.readCharSequence()`

example is here:

```
// here we use utf-8 decoding, you can choose the charset you want
String s = ByteBuf.readCharSequence(length, Charset.forName("utf-8")).toString()
```

note that `ByteBuf.readCharSequence()` returns `java.lang.CharSequence`, use `toString()` to get `String` obejct

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296386/netty-java-getting-data-from-bytebuf)

From there you can use `new String(byte[])` or some Base64 solution (since it's binary data I'm assuming)