# getting string content from FullHttpResponse byteBuf in Netty

Tags: netty

I have tried various flavors and all are giving giberish results.
But the response on the browser looks fine. (clean json String)

```
    FullHttpResponse response = (FullHttpResponse) msg;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[response.content().readableBytes()];
    response.content().readBytes(bytes);
    String result = new String(bytes);
```

The other one I tried as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164891/getting-string-from-netty-bytebuf) is

```
response.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
```

Both are gibberish like this

[image]

P.S: I use HttpObjectAggregator and HttpServerCodec in pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely looking at compressed data, since you are dealing with instances of `FullHttpResponse`, and most servers these days use compression, it is highly likely that your data is compressed.

To see the compression algorithm behind the compression, you should look into `response.headers().get(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_ENCODING)`

This can return a combination of differend values (separated by `,` in the case of multiple recordings):

- `gzip`: The data is compressed using GZip
- `deflate: The data is compressed using deflate
- `identity`: No compression has taken place
- `br`: The data is compressed using brotli

One advantage of using `FullHttpResponse` is that you don't have to worry about the transfer encoding in use, as it handles that for you.

Comment: can you give your thoughts on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600097/new-handlers-not-created-for-each-requests-in-netty

Comment: When I try to get the compression algorithm I only get null as a response, even thou I know that is not true. Using littleproxy-mitm.

Comment: @MrKrisey Could you print the transfer encoding, some combinations of proxies and other things use that header

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem. Another question: I use FullHttpResponse but the content is still compressed. Was that not what you meant with an advantage with FullHttpResponse?