# New handlers not created for each requests in netty

Tags: netty

I noticed that new instances of handlers are not created for each http request. I have few variables that are defined at instance level. These values are set based on request. from close inspection, I found that these values are not freshly set but has the value from the first request.

Here is my Handler code

```
@Component
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
public class CustomHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {

private final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
private final String foo;
private final String val;

@Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

        //parse the request and set the variables
        if (foo!=null) {
            foo = request.getUri()
        }
        if (val!=null) {
        val = getQueryParamsOf("key");
        }
        buf.append(val);
        }
}
```

The buffer doesn't cleared up. For each new request, I still see old buffer.
i.e if I make a request `/foobar?key=netty`

I see *buf = netty* in the first call.
subsequent calls, *buf = nettynetty* and *buf=nettynettynetty* and so on.
Besides, `foo` and `val` variables are never null after the first request.

My understanding was since new Handler will be created for each request. But since I have used `@ChannelHander.Sharable` may be same Handlers get reused

so I commented out `@ChannelHander.Sharable`, the first request goes through fine. From next request, I get the following error.

```
io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: my.example.handlers.CustomHandler is not a @Sharable handler, so can't be added or removed multiple times.
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.checkMultiplicity(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:625)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:208)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:409)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:396)
    at my.example.CustomInitializer.initChannel(CustomInitializer.java:35)
    at my.example.CustomInitializer.initChannel(CustomInitializer.java:16)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:113)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.handlerAdded(ChannelInitializer.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:637)
```

Here is my initializer code

CustomIniatializer

```
    public class CustomIniatializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {


    @Autowired
    private ChannelDuplexHandler customHandler;

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
        p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
        p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
        p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(8*1024, true));
        p.addLast(customHandler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things you have to remember when using a `ChannelInitializer`, is the fact that the method `initChannel` is called for every new connection that is opened.

Anything that requires an unique state should be constructed inside this method.

Looking at your code, I see that you are creating new instances of `LoggingHandler`, `HttpServerCodec` and `HttpObjectAggregator` correctly, but you are referencing to an "shared" instance of your `customHandler` class.

While you could solve your problem by just using `new CustomHandler ()` inside the `initChannel` method, you are actually showing differend intentions by using springs autowire system.

There are 2 other solutions we can use:

### Factory pattern

Instead of directly autowiring an instance of `ChannelDuplexHandler`, you need to wire an factory that produces instances of this class:

```java
public interface ChannelDuplexHandlerFactory {
    public ChannelDuplexHandler getChannelDuplexHandler();
}

@Component
public class ChannelDuplexHandlerFactoryImplementation implements ChannelDuplexHandlerFactory {
    public ChannelDuplexHandler getChannelDuplexHandler() {
        return new CustomHandler();
    }
}

public class CustomIniatializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Autowired
    private ChannelDuplexHandler customHandler;

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
        p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
        p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
        p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(8*1024, true));
        p.addLast(customHandler.getChannelDuplexHandler());
    }
}
```

### Using channel based fields, instead of class fields

One other solution that you could use is variables stored inside the current channel, this is a more-advanced technique that can be useful for certain situations:

```java
@Component
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
public class CustomHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {

    private static final AttributeKey<StringBuilder> BUF_KEY = AttributeKey.newInstance("BUF_KEY");
    private static final AttributeKey<String> FOO_KEY = AttributeKey.newInstance("FOO_KEY");
    private static final AttributeKey<String> VAL_KEY = AttributeKey.newInstance("VAL_KEY");

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        Channel ch = ctx.channel();
        final StringBuilder buf = ch.attr(BUF_KEY).get();
        String foo = ch.attr(FOO_KEY).get();
        String val = ch.attr(VAL_KEY).get();

        // Parse the request and set the variables
        if (foo != null) {
            foo = request.getUri()
        }
        if (val != null) {
            val = getQueryParamsOf("key");
        }
        buf.append(val);

        ch.attr(FOO_KEY).set(foo);
        ch.attr(VAL_KEY).set(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed couple of variables (buf and foo) from instance to method level scope. But I could not avoid val. so I used AttributeKey field based, since that seems more elegant in my use case

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem even with a new Handler() implementation

```
public class HttpServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
   @Override
   public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
       .....
       p.addLast("httprequest", new HttpServerHandler(config));
   }
}
```

HttpServerHander

```
private String uuid;

public HttpServerHandler(final StaticConfig staticConfig) {

    this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

}
```

This uuid is not unique for every call.