# Memory leakage in http listener using Netty

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, netty

I need some help with my java code. I have implemented a http listener using netty 4.1.5 final. The listener forwards the received data to a Kafka producer. While testing the http listener and kafka producer and everything seems fine for short run. But on the long run I have noticed that some memory leakage is happening.

I am using a data generator (Running on another machine) with 1500 parallel threads, each producing one packet every 1.5 seconds. Each packet is around 1.2 KB. When I just start the listener without bombarding any data it uses around 50MB, (Found using TOP command) and as soon as I start sending data it starts increasing drastically upto ~2.0GB and then it gradually decreases till it reaches around 900MB and stays constant. It increases to 2GB in about 25 - 30 minutes and comes down to 900MB in 5 minutes. But the weird thing is after being constant for around 3.5 hours, the memory usage started increasing again and it went upto around 3.1GB. I stopped the data simulators for a minute then and started them again. Upon doing this the memory usage remained constant at 3.1GB for another 4 hours. I don't know if that was some exceptional case because I didnt had time to test it for another 10 hours again.

I checked the GC for the process. I have attached a screen shot of the initial few minutes of GC.
Whats worrying me is that the memory shoot up initially and the memory DOESN'T go down even when I kill the simulators.
I also noticed that a full GC doesn't happen at all, atleast for the first 40 minutes I monitored the GC.

I am running this on 32GB 6 core box, openJDK 7, centos 6 shared by other processes like kafka, hbase which are active.

Netty version - 4.1.5 Final

I just want to know if there is some obvious memory leakage which I am missing out.

I have been stuck this for a while now.

Thanks in advance.

Listener code

```
public class Http_Listener extends listener implements Runnable {
    private ChannelFuture channel;
    private final EventLoopGroup masterGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    private final EventLoopGroup slaveGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    private int port;
    Thread t;
    Kafka_Producer kafka_producer = new Kafka_Producer("String");
    int counter = 1;

    public Http_Listener(int port)
    {       
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //For error logging
        PrintWriter pw;
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();

        //will be called when the program shuts down in any manner
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() { shutdown(); }
        });

        try
        {
            //Logging in new connection
            try {
              pw=new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream( new File("//home//hduser//java_codes//nettyDynamicListner//logs//logFile_"+ dateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".txt"),true));
              pw.println(date.toString() + " : Connected with port " + port +". - ");
              pw.close();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
             System.exit(0);
              System.out.println("Error opening the log file");
            }
            System.out.println("Binded with port " + port);

            final ServerBootstrap bootstrap =
                new ServerBootstrap()
                    .group(masterGroup, slaveGroup)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 8192)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>(){
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(final SocketChannel ch) throws Exception
                        {
                            ch.pipeline().addLast("codec", new HttpServerCodec());
                            ch.pipeline().addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(512*1024));
                            ch.pipeline().addLast("request", new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception
                                {
                                    //For stats logging
                                    PrintWriter pw;
                                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                                    Date date = new Date();
                                    String msgString = "";
                                    String statString;

                                    if (msg instanceof FullHttpRequest)
                                    {
                                        final FullHttpRequest request = (FullHttpRequest) msg;
                                        final String responseMessage = ""; 
                                        FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(
                                            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1,
                                            HttpResponseStatus.OK,
                                            copiedBuffer(responseMessage.getBytes())
                                        );

                                        if (request.headers().get("Connection") == "keep-alive"){
                                            response.headers().set("Connection", "keep-alive");
                                        }
                                        response.headers().set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
                                        response.headers().set("Content-Length", responseMessage.length());

                                        ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
                                        response.release();

                                        HttpHeaders headers = request.headers();
                                        for (String name : headers.names()) {
                                            msgString = msgString + name + ":" + headers.get(name) + ";";
                                        }
                                        msgString = msgString + "\n";
                                        msgString = msgString + request.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
                                        //System.out.println(msgString);
                                        //System.out.println(counter++);

                                        kafka_producer.sendMessage("topic_"+Integer.toString(port), msgString);

                                        //Port stats log
                                        statString = date.toString() + "," + ctx.channel().remoteAddress().toString() + "," +  msgString.length();
                                        try {
                                              pw=new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream( new File("//home//hduser//java_codes//nettyDynamicListner//logs//" + port +"_portStats_"+ dateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".txt"),true));
                                              pw.println(statString);
                                              pw.close();
                                          } catch(Exception ex) {
                                              System.out.println("Error opening the log file");
                                          }

                                          request.release();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception
                                {
                                    ctx.flush();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception
                                {
                                    //For error logging
                                    PrintWriter pw;
                                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                                    Date date = new Date();

                                    //Logging error
                                    try {
                                        pw=new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream( new File("//home//hduser//java_codes//nettyDynamicListner//logs//logFile_"+ dateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".txt"),true));
                                        pw.println(date.toString() + " : Error in port " + port +". - " + cause.getMessage());
                                          pw.close();
                                      } catch(Exception ex) {
                                        System.out.println("Error opening the log file");
                                      }
                                    ByteBuf responseBuf = copiedBuffer(cause.getMessage().getBytes());
                                    FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(
                                            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1,
                                            HttpResponseStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                                            responseBuf
                                        );
                                    ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
                                    responseBuf.release();
                                    response.release();
                                }                                    
                            });
                        }
                    })
                    .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
            channel = bootstrap.bind(port).sync();
        }
        catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            //Error logging
            try {
                  pw=new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream( new File("//home//hduser//java_codes//nettyDynamicListner//logs//logFile_"+ dateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".txt"),true));
                  pw.println(date.toString() + " : Interrupted exception in port " + port +". - " + e.getMessage());
                  pw.close();
              } catch(Exception ex) {
                  System.out.println("Error opening the log file");
                  ex.printStackTrace();
             System.exit(0);
              }
        }
    }



    @Override
    int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    @Override
    boolean isAlive() {
        return t.isAlive();
    }

    public void shutdown()
    {
        //For error logging
        PrintWriter pw;
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();

        slaveGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        masterGroup.shutdownGracefully();

        try
        {
            channel.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { }

        //Logging connection disconnect
        try {
              pw=new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream( new File("//home//hduser//java_codes//nettyDynamicListner//logs//logFile_"+ dateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".txt"),true));
              pw.println(date.toString() + " : Disconnected from port " + port +". - ");
              pw.close();
          } catch(Exception ex) {
              System.out.println("Error opening the log file");
          }
    }
}
```

Kafka Producer

```
public class Kafka_Producer {
    Properties props;
    PrintWriter pw;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Producer producer;

    /* Value of valSerializer should be either 'Byte' or 'String', anything other 
     * than 'Byte' will be considered as 'String'. This is to avoid the creation
     * of a new Producer for each data packet
     */
    Kafka_Producer(String valSerializer) {
         props = new Properties();
         props.put("bootstrap.servers", "servers");
         props.put("acks", "1");
         props.put("retries", 0);
         props.put("batch.size", 800);
         props.put("linger.ms", 10);
         props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
         props.put("max.block.ms", 2500);
         props.put("timeout.ms", 2000);
         props.put("request.timeout.ms", 2000);
         props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

         //To determine the type of producer to be initialized
         if(valSerializer.toLowerCase() == "byte") {
         props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
         producer = new KafkaProducer<String, byte[]>(props);
         } else {
             props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
             producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
         }
    }

    //For http messages
    public void sendMessage(String topic, String msg) {
        try {
            /*
             * Calling future.get is performance in effective, but since we need 
             * to make sure every data packet is send successfully else written to a 
             * file, we take this performance hit. 
             */
            Future<RecordMetadata> future=producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, msg));
            future.get();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            Date date = new Date();
            try {
                  pw=new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream( new File("D:\\Work\\nettyDynamicListner\\logs\\" + topic + "_failedMessage_"+ dateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".txt"),true));
                  pw.println(date.toString() + ":" + topic + ":" + msg);
                  pw.close();
              } catch(Exception ex) {
                  System.out.println("Error opening the failed message log file");
              }
        }
    }
}
```

GC LOG

[image: GC output of first few minutes]

Comment: "it uses around 50MB" - how do you measure that?

Comment: @the8472 Using the top command in linux.

Comment: then you have no indication of a leak yet. the GCs may hold onto memory without that memory being occupied by objects.

Comment: If you really want to understand if there is a leak you will need to take a heapdump and analyse it.

Comment: @NormanMaurer Turns out I have to close the channel if it is not a keepalive connection.

Adding the following did the trick.  
`if(!HttpUtil.isKeepAlive(request)){                 channelFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE); }`   


But I dont understand why I should close the channel explicitly.  

And converting a ByteBuf to string was a very expensive operation, so I took the bytes of the buffer and converted it to string. Referring to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309312/2368687)